# Force update all posts in custom post type, no content changes

Tags: posts, functions, automation

I have imported data from a custom post type that has location data for a map plugin (Progress Map). I have about 500+ posts each with different location data. For some reason the location data isn't registered unless I save each post again.

I've been looking for a way to quickly automate this but no one seems to have a solution that doesn't involve also changing data on each post which I don't want to do.

I thought there would be a simple snippet that you can change the post type on. I'm not a programmer so a lot of this goes over my head.

## Related Articles

- [How can I bulk update all posts without making changes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177021/how-can-i-bulk-update-all-posts-without-making-changes)
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134642/update-all-posts-in-one-go
- [Update all posts at once](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43907/update-all-posts-at-once)
- [How to update all post at once?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127632/how-to-update-all-post-at-once)
- [WordPress Tutorial: Update all posts at once](http://kakoma.ug/code/2013/09/wordpress-tutorial-update-posts-category)

## Update/My Fix

It turns out that with the Progress Map plugin you can regenerate the data for all the locations. So in effect I solved MY problem but not the specific problem I was asking about.

I'm unsure if this counts as an answer so I'll leave it here and keep this as un-answered.

For pins(location data) not appearing on the overall map you can regenerate the locations:
Go to “Troubleshooting & configs” and click on the button “Regenerate markers”.

## Update 2020-03-28

- Another similar question: [How to force update all posts after import](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/294575/how-to-force-update-all-posts-after-import)
- Potential Solution: [WordPress Tutorial: Update all posts at once](https://kakoma.ug/code/2013/09/wordpress-tutorial-update-posts-category)

## Update 2021-03-26 (ACF Fields)

- Helpful if you're trying to update ACF fields in bulk after creating a new field for existing posts: [ACF Forums: Update all posts at once](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/update-all-posts-at-once/)
- Another helpful slice of code for ACF mass updates: [Update All ACF Post Fields](https://jboullion.com/update-acf-post-fields/)

Comment: You've mentioned _has location data_ What kind of data ? Custom fields, taxonomies ?

Comment: It would most likely be a custom field. It's longitude and latitude that you input. All other custom fields and taxonomies attached to the custom post are fine.

Comment: Then you just need to use [`update_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) But you must know what data need to update in which format! You do not need to use `wp_update_post( $my_post );`

Comment: I don't actually need to change any data. I need the current data to re-save. When I open the post I can see the saved latitude and longitude, it just doesn't seem to be getting picked up. Hopefully that makes sense. Can you do that with update_post_meta( )?

Perhaps 'Update' is the wrong terminology?

Comment: That is complicated till you find what is actual problem. When data is there then why it doesn't getting picked up! If something is written keeping in mind that you are on post edit screen then it won't work. It is something like _Trial and error_ It might be possible that it will work or may be not. You can run it, after making a database backup. Good Luck!

Comment: Turns out there's a way to regenerate this data using a function in the plugin itself.

Comment: please post your solution. Having the same problem.

Comment: So sad to see no answer for this.