# Update around 200,000 posts

Tags: migration, wp-update-post, plugin-polylang

So I have recently migrated from a regular site to a wordpress CMS all via MySQL. I successfully was able to adapt the old database with that of WordPress.

Now, the site has content in 3 languages. I am using polylang to achieve that. I have successfully created the taxonomy relationships and I can see that all my posts have the required language id. I also have around 60 Categories. Polylang has a feature where if the post is updated (not the database update) the required categories are created on the fly in the posts' language. I have tested this with a manual update and it works. But the problem is I am unable to find a solution to bulk update all the posts together at once.

[I tried what is written here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/294575/how-to-force-update-all-posts-after-import) But then I just get an error 500 when I reload the site ("localhost is unable to handle this request). First I thought that this is an error of the memory limits and execution time. I have set it all to unlimited but with no success. I am using BITNAMI WAMP stack on Windows as my development server.

Any help will be a great one!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned setting the memory limits and execution time to unlimited, so this may not be the right answer. I thought I'd mention it anyway since it may help.

Since you have so much content, you'll have to find ways to accomplish this in the background rather than during the request. This is the perfect situations for [scheduled tasks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event).

This would allow you to schedule an update that will run when cron runs rather than within the scope of the request.

You can also use [WP CLI](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/installing/) to write a command that will accomplish this. This allows you to run this manually and/or schedule this with cron.

Hope this helps.